# What cars were used with the Crocodile Class Ce 6/8 locomotive during its active years, especially at the beginning?

Tags: 20th-century, 1920s, switzerland, railroads

The [Crocodile Class Ce 6/8 locomotive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_(locomotive)#Class_Ce_6/8) was manufactured around a century ago, between 1919 and 1927. It was used by Swiss Federal Railways.

Wikipedia claims that

> These locomotives were developed for pulling heavy goods trains on the steep tracks of the Gotthardbahn from Lucerne to Chiasso, including the Gotthard Tunnel.

Sadly, I can't Google up any photos or model numbers of cars it was actually pulling during that time. So, what cars was this locomotive really used with? Especially at the beginning of its service, in 1920s?

From the description, I understood it was made for tracks where conventional, rigid locomotives were either too weak, or too long. Thus, I expect not all cars in that era to be able to ride the same routes. If that assumption is wrong, I'll be glad to know too.

Comment: What's wrong with simply going by epoch for the types like Falls, Fs-u and Uacs?

Comment: @LangLangC 1) I don't know where exactly I should look and 2) I'd like to know what was actually used with this locomotive. For goods I think I can probably assume if it existed it probably was, for passengers not so much.

Comment: As sole engine it wasn't used for passengers, but as an adjunct for extra-power difficult/steep tracks. But that's also the main reason for intro of this type: be able to pull x tons at y% inclination — as load on the otherwise independently standardized cars/wagons attached to it and other engines. That's why I do not really understand the question: do you assume that this locomotive had specially designed cars to go with it/just for this? (If yes: please add that assumption explicitly to the Qtext.)

Comment: @LаngLаngС question updated.

Answer (score 2):

goods wagoons ? or passenger cars ?
SBB acquired Leichtstahlwagen in the 30s which then basically made how SBB looked the next 50 years.

[German language wiki about Leichtstahlwagen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leichtstahlwagen_(SBB))

Someone has this site: [Bahnbilder von Max](http://bahnbilder-von-max.ch/sbb/strecke-aarau-lenzburg-wohlen-rotkreuz-arth-goldau/index.html)

Because the line definitely had a lot of cross-Europe traffic : so
almost any european guterwagen which was certified to go to foreign countries. Berne gauge to begin with.

In the case of SJ (Swedish State railway), a small number of types were not allowed to run abroad.

[Railvetica Die Historischen Umbau Stahlwagen](https://www.railvetica.ch/Fahrzeuge/B-8102/8112/)

SBB built the Be 4/6 as its passenger locomotive for the Gotthard bahn look at [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBB_Be_/6_12303-12342](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBB_Be_4/6_12303-12342)

Comment: Going by the quote in Q, I'd guess that it is about goods?

Comment: @LangLangC & Stefan Skoglund I was interested in goods wagons as that's what crocodile is described to be created for. In my language there is no distinction between wagons and cars. Passenger ones are interesting too, but I'll be hesitant to believe they were used with this locomotive merely because they existed in the same time and country. Any suggestions how to pit that into my question without language mistakes will be most welcome.

Comment: Compare the speed for Be 4/6 and Ce 6/8 II : 75 and 65 km/h.  Gotthardbahn didnt really permit higher speeds from the beginning. To high speed at downhill : that is a clear risk of a runaway train and uphill is demanding of the engine. I would expect that the main reason why Ce 6/8 wasnt used on passenger trains were the demands on them for freight service.

Comment: For modells of goods wagoon : epoche II and they can be from most of continental Europe except  Spain/Portugal except that as i wrote: some types from one administration isn't permitted to leave the owner's  area.